# prevent user from entring 0 as a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to prevent user from entering 0 in the input box.

HTML code :

```
<input class="billMenuQuantity" type="number" name="quantity">
```

Jquery code:

```
   $('.billMenuQuantity').on('keyup keydown', function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() < 1 && e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 8) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(1);
        }
    });
```

It's preventing the user from entering the 0 but it's also preventing the user from entering the any other single digit number(i.e 2-9) other than 1.It is accepting the double digit number(i.e 11, 12 etc).

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just test `code === 96` and length of the `input-value`

```js
$('.billMenuQuantity').on('keyup keydown', function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (this.value.length === 0 && code === 96) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="billMenuQuantity" type="number" name="quantity">
```

Comment: This would prevent entering of numbers like 20 or 100.

Comment: It worked but as @JeremyHarris mentioned it's preventing numbers like 20 or 100. I want to just prevent the user from entering 0.

Comment: @JeremyHarris, I was going to make an edit and OP says this is what he wanted.. Quiet confusing state..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`$(this).val() == 0` instead of `$(this).val() < 1`

```
$('.billMenuQuantity').on('keyup keydown', function (e) {
    if ($(this).val() == 0 && e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(1);
    }
});
```